# Control Template or Custom Dependency property

Tags: wpf, user-controls, custom-controls

I have a checkbox control which is templated as follows:

[image]

Here is the XAML snippet of the checkbox:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0" 
          Grid.Column="1" 
          Width="62"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          IsChecked="{Binding IncludeBlueTrades}"
          Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchCheckBox}"/>
```

Currently the Values: Buy and Sell are hardcoded into the Style. I want to get them configurable so that the checkbox can pass this values. Basically everytime I want to use the checkbox as a slider - I should be able to pass the values from XAML - something like below:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0" 
          Grid.Column="1" 
          Width="62"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          ValueOn = "Buy"
          ValueOff = "Sell"
          IsChecked="{Binding IncludeBlueTrades}"
          Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchCheckBox}"/>
```

I understand the concepts of Template Binding (which has to be used in Control Template) and custom controls. What I am confused here is which one should I use to get the achieved result. I think it has to be custom dependency property - but not 100 % sure.

I can post the style code is necessary. Can someone please help me with code snippet and direction.

Thanks

Comment: Custom DP is a way to go.

Comment: Possible if somebody can share a code snippet for this specific example